# Perfomance Issues while capturing and processing a video

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I'm currently working on a project where I need to display a processed live video capture. Therefore, I'm using something similar to this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0); 
if (!cap.isOpened()) 
    return -1;

cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);

cv::namedWindow("Current Capture");
for (;;)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;       
    cv::Mat mirrored;
    cv::flip(frame, mirrored, 1);
    cv::imshow("Current Capture", process_image(mirrored));

    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
```

The problem I have is, that `process_image`, which perfomes a circle detection in the image, needs some time to finish and causes the displaying to be rather a slideshow then a video.

My Question is: How can I speed up the processing **without** manipulating the `process_image` function?

I thought about performing the image processing in another thread, but I'm not really sure how to start. Do you have any other idea than this?

PS.: I'm not expecting you to write code for me, I only need a point to start from ;)

**EDIT:**

Ok, if there is nothing i can do about the performance while capturing, I will need to change the `process_image` function.

```
cv::Mat process_image(cv::Mat img)
{
    cv::Mat hsv;
    cv::medianBlur(img, img, 7);
    cv::cvtColor(img, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    cv::Mat lower_hue_range; // lower and upper hue range  in case of red color
    cv::Mat upper_hue_range;
    cv::inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(LOWER_HUE1, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(UPPER_HUE1, 255, 255), lower_hue_range);
    cv::inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(LOWER_HUE2, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(UPPER_HUE1, 255, 255), upper_hue_range);

    /// Combine the above two images
    cv::Mat hue_image;
    cv::addWeighted(lower_hue_range, 1.0, upper_hue_range, 1.0, 0.0, hue_image);

    /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
    cv::GaussianBlur(hue_image, hue_image, cv::Size(13, 13), 2, 2);

    /// store all found circles here
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
    cv::HoughCircles(hue_image, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, hue_image.rows / 8, 100, 20, 0, 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        /// circle center
        cv::circle(hsv, cv::Point(circles[i][0], circles[i][1]), 3, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
        /// circle outline
        cv::circle(hsv, cv::Point(circles[i][0], circles[i][1]), circles[i][2], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
    }

    cv::Mat newI;
    cv::cvtColor(hsv, newI, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);

    return newI;
}
```

Is there a huge perfomance issue I can do anything about?

Comment: 1ms is quite short, not surprising you have performance issues.

Comment: Oh sorry this was just something I tried . I originally tried it with 30ms. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the process_image function is what is causing the bottle neck in your program, but you can't modify it, then there's not really a lot you can do. If that function takes longer to execute than the duration of a video frame then you will never get what you need.

How about reducing the quality of the video capture or reducing the size? At the moment I can see you have it set to 1280*720. If the process_image function has less data to work with it should execute faster.

Comment: Hmm. Okay this is actually what i thought... reducing the resolution works, however, it also reduces the resulting quality. I will try to get access to the code of  `process_image`. Maybe it can be optimized.